# Retrofit2 working fine on emulator but after generating signed APK , it gives java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp, openai-api

I want to call OpenAI Chat-gpt-3.5 turbo API using Retrofit in Android Java application for my chat application , but while testing in Android Studio emulator and in debugging devices its working fine ,
but in after making a signed APK , while calling the api it start giving error i.e.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for interface d6.g                                                                                  for method a.a                                                                                at e4.a.O(SourceFile:40)                                                                                at d6.y0.a(SourceFile:2751)                                                                                 at d6.x0.b(SourceFile:25)                                                                           at d6.w0.invoke(SourceFile:45).....
and  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Call return type must be parameterized as Call or Call<? extends Foo>.....
Please if anybody know the problem help me solve this , i tried every possible solution available ,
also i am begineer in using retrofit

//here is my request function :

```
private void sendRequest(String query) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put ( "model","gpt-3.5-turbo" );
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray ();
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject ();
            jsonObject1.put ( "role","system" );
            jsonObject1.put ( "content",query );
            jsonArray.put ( 0, jsonObject1);
            jsonObject.put("messages",jsonArray);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d ( TAG,e.getMessage () );
            throw new RuntimeException ( e );
        }
        RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return MediaType.parse("application/json");
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                sink.writeUtf8(jsonObject.toString());
            }
        };
        Call<ChatCompletionResponse> call = RetrofitInstance.getInstance ().apiInterface.getData ( requestBody );
        call.enqueue ( new Callback<ChatCompletionResponse> () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ChatCompletionResponse> call, @NonNull Response<ChatCompletionResponse> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful ()){
                    assert response.body () != null;
                    String content = response.body ().getChoices ()[0].getMessage ().getContent ();
                    TextMessage textMessage = new TextMessage ( user.getUid (),content, CometChatConstants.RECEIVER_TYPE_USER );
                    textMessage.setSender ( user );
                    addMessage ( textMessage );
                    setIndicator ( false );
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ChatCompletionResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d ( TAG,"failurse occued" + t.getMessage () );
                String msg = "Request failed !!";
                TextMessage textMessage = new TextMessage ( logedinuser.getUid (),msg, CometChatConstants.RECEIVER_TYPE_USER );
                textMessage.setSender ( logedinuser );
                addMessage ( textMessage );
            }
        } );
    }
```

// And My RetrofitInstance.java class :

```
public class RetrofitInstance {
    public static RetrofitInstance instance;
    public APIInterface apiInterface;
    static String BASE_URL = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/";
    RetrofitInstance(){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor () {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AppKeys.GPT_TOKEN )
                                .build();
                        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                    }
                })
                .build();


        apiInterface = new Retrofit.Builder ()
                .client ( client )
                .baseUrl ( BASE_URL )
                .addConverterFactory ( GsonConverterFactory.create () )
                .build ().create ( APIInterface.class );
    }
    public static RetrofitInstance getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new RetrofitInstance ();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

// My API Interface :

```
public interface APIInterface {
    @POST("completions")
    Call<ChatCompletionResponse> getData(
            @Body RequestBody body
    );
}
```

//And ChatCompletionResponse.java class :

```
public class ChatCompletionResponse {
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public long getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public UsageData getUsage() {
        return usage;
    }

    public Choice[] getChoices() {
        return choices;
    }

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setObject(String object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void setCreated(long created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void setUsage(UsageData usage) {
        this.usage = usage;
    }

    public void setChoices(Choice[] choices) {
        this.choices = choices;
    }

    @SerializedName("object")
    private String object;

    @SerializedName("created")
    private long created;

    public ChatCompletionResponse(String id, String object, long created, String model, UsageData usage, Choice[] choices) {
        this.id = id;
        this.object = object;
        this.created = created;
        this.model = model;
        this.usage = usage;
        this.choices = choices;
    }

    @SerializedName("model")
    private String model;

    @SerializedName("usage")
    private UsageData usage;

    @SerializedName("choices")
    private Choice[] choices;

    // Getters and setters

    public static class UsageData {
        @SerializedName("prompt_tokens")
        private int promptTokens;

        @SerializedName("completion_tokens")
        private int completionTokens;

        @SerializedName("total_tokens")
        private int totalTokens;

        // Getters and setters
    }

    public static class Choice {
        public Choice(Message message, String finishReason, int index) {
            this.message = message;
            this.finishReason = finishReason;
            this.index = index;
        }

        public void setMessage(Message message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void setFinishReason(String finishReason) {
            this.finishReason = finishReason;
        }

        public void setIndex(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        @SerializedName("message")
        private Message message;

        public Message getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public String getFinishReason() {
            return finishReason;
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        @SerializedName("finish_reason")
        private String finishReason;

        @SerializedName("index")
        private int index;

        // Getters and setters
    }

    public static class Message {
        @SerializedName("role")
        private String role;

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public Message(String role, String content) {
            this.role = role;
            this.content = content;
        }

        public void setRole(String role) {
            this.role = role;
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        @SerializedName("content")
        private String content;

        // Getters and setters
    }
}
```

Comment: have you written `progaurd-rules` ?

Comment: No , i haven't added any progaurd-rules related to  retrofit , i will add them now if that sort my problem, thanks

Comment: Also you need to write progaurd rules in order to prevent your data classes from being obfuscated while creating release build.